# Error #1064 in creating function in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

friends.

I am trying to create function in MySQL using this script:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CurrentMemoDepartment(MID INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  DECLARE DeptID INT;
  SET DeptID = 0;
  SELECT TOP 1 TDeptID INTO DeptID FROM Transactions WHERE MemoID = MID ORDER BY ID DESC;
  RETURN DeptID;
END
```

but it says:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single-statement function does not need in BEGIN-END, intermediate variables, DELIMITER reassing.

And MySQL uses `LIMIT`, not `TOP n`.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION CurrentMemoDepartment(MID INT)
RETURNS INT
RETURN SELECT TDeptID 
       FROM Transactions 
       WHERE MemoID = MID 
       ORDER BY ID DESC
       LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

USE DELIMITER for declaring

like

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION CurrentMemoDepartment(MID INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  DECLARE DeptID INT;
  SET DeptID = 0;
  SELECT TDeptID INTO DeptID FROM Transactions WHERE MemoID = MID ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
  RETURN DeptID;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Top is sql server Limit is mysql

Comment: Accepted, my friend. But can you explain for me what is "DELIMITER"?

Comment: mysql has know where a command starts and ends, usually it is with a semicolon. but you are defining a function/stored procedure, which is all text for mysql so you must give him a hint what to look for the internal sqlstaetment and in your  case it ends with END$$ After that you put it back to normal